# Access hydra configuration within decorated method

Tags: fb-hydra

I would like to access hydra configuration, e.g., sweeper, from the decorated function:

```
@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: Config) -> None:
    OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg.hydra.sweeper)
```

Is there any parameter I can pass to `@hydra.main()` not to remove that configuration, or is there other place where I can find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from hydra.core.hydra_config import HydraConfig

@hydra.main()
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(HydraConfig.get().sweeper)
```

You can also access it through the configuration with interpolation:

config.yaml:

```yaml
hydra_sweeper: ${hydra:sweeper}
```

See [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/configure_hydra/intro/#runtime-variables).